# IIS CanonicalHostNameRule for different wrong subdomains

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7, redirect

I currently have this CanonicalHostNameRule.
We have multiple top-level domains (.ch and .de), that is why we don't use the default CanonicalHostNameRule from IIS.

```
<rule name="RedirectToWWW" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www)(\S+)\.(de?|ch)$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{C:0}/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

This works for

http://supertext.ch

But not for

http://holdrio.supertext.ch
http://ww.w.supertext.ch
http://www.mail.supertext.ch

and I really would like something that redirects any subdomain to www.supertext.ch or .de respectively. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use following pattern: `^(?!www\.supertext\.[de|ch])(\S+)\.(de|ch)$`

The results would be for example:

holdrio.supertext.ch ->

- {C:0}: holdrio.supertext.ch
- {C:1}: holdrio.supertext
- {C:2}: ch

holdrio.supertext.de->

- {C:0} holdrio.supertext.de
- {C:1} holdrio.supertext
- {C:2} de

supertext.ch->

- {C:0} supertext.ch
- {C:1} supertext
- {C:2} ch

```xml
<rule name="RedirectToWWW" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www\.supertext\.[de|ch])(\S+)\.(de|ch)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.supertext.{C:2}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
```

Note: www.supertext.ch.supertext.ch is not covered

I hope this works for you.